# Parallel.For throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel.for

I'm trying to parallelize code for UI generation in a Rimworld mod. While the UI generates fine it throws `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.
Happens everytime the `Parallel.For(1, X, options, i =>` is called. Did try `lock` inside the parallelized `for` loop but it defeats the purpouse.

Error message below:

```
Exception from long event: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
  at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException (System.ExceptionArgument argument, System.ExceptionResource resource) [0x00029] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
  at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException () [0x00000] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
  at FluffyResearchTree.Tree+<>c__DisplayClass34_0.<MinimizeCrossings>b__0 (System.Int32 i) [0x0005b] in <fb792a3ef31540608dfda3c3957bc6c1>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel+<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1[TLocal].<ForWorker>b__1 () [0x0020b] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg (System.Threading.Tasks.Task childTask) [0x00000] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task+<>c__DisplayClass178_0.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__0 (System.Object <p0>) [0x00086] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (System.Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) [0x00011] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait (System.Int32 millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00043] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait () [0x00000] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[TLocal] (System.Int32 fromInclusive, System.Int32 toExclusive, System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelOptions parallelOptions, System.Action`1[T] body, System.Action`2[T1,T2] bodyWithState, System.Func`4[T1,T2,T3,TResult] bodyWithLocal, System.Func`1[TResult] localInit, System.Action`1[T] localFinally) [0x001ab] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For (System.Int32 fromInclusive, System.Int32 toExclusive, System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelOptions parallelOptions, System.Action`1[T] body) [0x0001c] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
  at FluffyResearchTree.Tree.MinimizeCrossings () [0x0005f] in <fb792a3ef31540608dfda3c3957bc6c1>:0 
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) Verse.LongEventHandler.Verse.LongEventHandler.UpdateCurrentSynchronousEvent_Patch2(bool&)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
  at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException (System.ExceptionArgument argument, System.ExceptionResource resource) [0x00029] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
  at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException () [0x00000] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
  at FluffyResearchTree.Tree+<>c__DisplayClass34_0.<MinimizeCrossings>b__0 (System.Int32 i) [0x0005b] in <fb792a3ef31540608dfda3c3957bc6c1>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel+<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1[TLocal].<ForWorker>b__1 () [0x0020b] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg (System.Threading.Tasks.Task childTask) [0x00000] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task+<>c__DisplayClass178_0.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__0 (System.Object <p0>) [0x00086] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 <---
```

Code snippet below:

```
public static void MinimizeCrossings()
        {
            // initialize each layer by putting nodes with the most (recursive!) children on bottom
            //shown in-game as "reducing crossings"
            Log.Debug("Minimize crossings.");
            Profiler.Start();

            int X = Size.x;
            var options = new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((Environment.ProcessorCount * 0.75) * 2.0)) };
            Parallel.For(1, X, options, i =>
            {
                var nodes = Layer(X).OrderBy(n => n.Descendants.Count).ToList();
                for (var z = 0; z < nodes.Count; z++)
                {
                    nodes[i].Y = i + 1;
                }
            });

            // up-down sweeps of mean reordering
            var progress = false;
            int iteration = 0, burnout = 2, max_iterations = 50;
            while ((!progress || burnout > 0) && iteration < max_iterations)
            {
                progress = BarymetricSweep(iteration++);
                if (!progress)
                    burnout--;
            }

            // greedy sweep for local optima
            iteration = 0;
            burnout = 2;
            while (burnout > 0 && iteration < max_iterations)
            {
                progress = GreedySweep(iteration++);
                if (!progress)
                    burnout--;
            }

            Profiler.End();
        }
```

Full code for context: https://github.com/Zemogiter/ResearchTree

Comment: I don't think this is the issue but the `z` for loop is curious.  It does not use `z` and does the same line `z` times.

Comment: @SteveWong no , i assume thats the bug, that eventually i gets too big

Comment: Yep, looping with `z`, but using `i` as index. You are assigning `nodes[i].Y = i + 1;` multiple times `(nodes.Count) times' . The same value. You might want to replace the `i` with `z`

Comment: Ok so I replaced i with z except for the i after options because that would give me a compiler error. The exception is gone but the `MinimizeCrossings` method now executes slower. I'm guessing it's because `nodes` is of type that is not thread-safe. Am I correct?

Comment: does order matter for you? if not you could use [concurrent bag] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Well the order matters because the menu is suppoused to show research option in order of their group (Neolithic, Medival, Industrial, Spacer, Ultra etc.)